# How to load seeders from Laravel packages, without publishing them?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing some packages for Laravel (for internal use).

It is logical for a package, to have its own seeders.

For example, let's suppose we are creating a package called `Company\Geo` that has the data of countries and continents and flags, etc.

It's a good UX that this package should have 100% self-contained seeder classes to populate the database tables with the data.

However, I'm stuck at running seeders from packages. This is my package directory strcuture:

```
- host => (a laravel app to test the package)
   - WebSite
       - packages
           - Company
               - FirstPackage
                   - database
                       - migrations
                       - seeders
                           - FirstSeeder.php
                   - src
                       - Models
                       - Http
                           - Controllers
```

And here is my `FirstSeeder.php` code:

```
<?php

namespace Company\FirstPackage\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class FirstSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // code to seed
    }
}
```

And here is my `composer.json` of the `Company\FirstPackage` package:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "/database/migrations"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Company\\FirstPackage\\": "src/",
        "Company\\FirstPackage\\Database\\": "database/"
    }
},
```

Yet when I run `php artisan db:seed --class=FirstSeeder` I get this error:

> Target class [Database\Seeders\FirstSeeder] does not exist.

How can I call seeders of my package, without publishing them to the host package?

Comment: Did you try with absolute path of the --class while you were seeding?

Comment: @user3532758, Yes. I tried `php artisan db:seed --class=Company\Package\Database\Seeder\FirstSeeder.php` and I received the same error.

Comment: I'm trying to do this too, can't find anything on it really.

Answer (score 1):

I have just read the source code. I believe you got to do this:

```
// Pls use double backward slashes.
php artisan db:seed --class=php artisan db:seed --class=Company\\Package\\Database\\Seeder\\FirstSeeder
```

You might want to take a look at the `Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::getSeeder()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the same logic that is used in ServiceProvider. This way you can simply run: php artisan db:seed and it should run any seeders you have in your packages.**

```
 protected function loadSeeders($seed_list){
$this->callAfterResolving(DatabaseSeeder::class, function ($seeder) use ($seed_list) {
            foreach ((array) $seed_list as $path) {
                $seeder->call($seed_list);
                // here goes the code that will print out in console that the migration was succesful
            }
        });
    }
```

**then you can create a list using a function that gets every class name you are using in your package. And put it inside, like this**

```
$seed_list[] = 'Vendor/Name/Directory/ClassName'
 // inside your service provider 
boot()
{
$this->loadSeeders($seed_list)
}
```

*this is just a copy past please see*
*https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/best-way-to-load-seeds-and-routes-from-a-package*